# Valgrind errors, Invalid read of size & conditional jump or move depens on uninitialised value

Tags: c, valgrind

I've got those two errors and could need some help to find a solution after searching for a long time:

```
==4902== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==4902== Invalid read of size 1
==4902==    at 0x4010A0: getData (main.c:321)
==4902==    by 0x402527: main (main.c:783)
==4902==  Address 0x52007af is 1 bytes before a block of size 2,152 alloc'd
==4902==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4902==    by 0x400FF1: getData (main.c:309)
==4902==    by 0x402527: main (main.c:783)
==4902== 
==4902== 
==4902== 1 errors in context 2 of 2:
==4902== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4902==    at 0x4C2E0E9: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4902==    by 0x40107A: getData (main.c:319)
==4902==    by 0x402527: main (main.c:783)
==4902==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==4902==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4902==    by 0x400FF1: getData (main.c:309)
==4902==    by 0x402527: main (main.c:783)
```

```c
  char** buffer = malloc(file_size * sizeof(char**));
  if(buffer == NULL)
  {
    status = EXITCODE_4;
    return status;
  }

  int buffer_counter = 0;
  int buffer_length = 0;

 while(!feof(datafile))
  {
    buffer[buffer_counter] = malloc(file_size * sizeof(char*));
    if(buffer[buffer_counter] == NULL)
    {
      status = EXITCODE_4;
      free2D(buffer, buffer_counter);
      return status;
    }

    fgets(buffer[buffer_counter], file_size, datafile);

    buffer_length = strlen(buffer[buffer_counter]) - 1;

    if((buffer[buffer_counter][buffer_length]) == NEWLINE)
      buffer[buffer_counter][buffer_length] = 0;
    buffer_counter++;
  }
```

line 309 is where the second malloc happens,
321 the if
and 319 the strlen

i'm not very experienced with valgrind, so i don't know how to fix that.
Thx for any help i can get.

Comment: `while(!feof(datafile))` [is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: this line: '' buffer[buffer_counter] = malloc(file_size * sizeof(char*)); should be: ' buffer[buffer_counter] = malloc(file_size);' because want an array of char, not an array of pointer to char

Comment: should clear the initial malloc'd array to all NULL to make it (relatively) easy when it comes time to free all the memory allocations

Comment: suggest either performing first line allocation before the while loop and control the while loop with fgets() --or-- use getline() and then no separate calls to malloc other than the initial list of pointers.

Comment: `char** buffer = malloc(file_size * sizeof(char**));` also mallocs the wrong data type. To avoid this error use `sizeof *buffer` instead of naming a type explicitly

Comment: Not explicitly mentioned yet, but the reason you get the valgrind error comes from after the last line `fgets` fails, so `buffer[buffer_counter]` contains uninitialized values and then you call `strlen` on garbage.  To avoid this sort of error always check return values of I/O functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
while (!feof(datafile))
```

with

```
while (fgets(buffer[buffer_counter], file_size, datafile) != NULL)
```

because `while (!feof(datafile))` will iterate once beyond the end of the file, read [why `while (!feof(datafile))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

The `EOF` marker is set after `fgets()` attempts to read past the end of file, so it requires one extra iteration for that to happen, but `fgets()` will return `NULL` at the end of file, so you will be safe from accessing uninitialized values if you test for it in the `while` loop condition.

Of course you will need to rethink the program flow, i suggest this

```
char** buffer = malloc(file_size * sizeof(char *));
if (buffer == NULL)
{
    status = EXITCODE_4;
    return status;
}

int  buffer_counter = 0;
int  buffer_length  = 0;
char line[file_size];

while (fgets(line, file_size, datafile) != NULL)
{
    size_t length;

    length = strlen(line);
    if (line[length - 1] == NEWLINE)
      line[--length] = '\0';
    buffer[buffer_counter] = malloc(1 + length);
    if (buffer[buffer_counter] == NULL)
    {
      status = EXITCODE_4;
      free2D(buffer, buffer_counter);
      return status;
    }
    strcpy(buffer[buffer_counter], line);
    buffer_counter++;
}
```

also, `malloc(file_size * sizeof(char *))` is allocating more memory than you need, you need `malloc(file_size * sizeof(char))`, and `sizeof(char) == 1` so just `malloc(file_size)`, I fixed it anyway to allocate space for the exact string to fit.

Comment: @PinkieClownie by the way I am very happy to see that you check for `malloc()`'s return value. Keep that style, and you will be very happy, trust me.

Answer (score 0):

here is a suggested fix for the problems

```
char** buffer = malloc(file_size * sizeof(char**));
if(buffer == NULL)
{
    status = EXITCODE_4;
    return status;
}

// implied else, malloc successful

// clear list of pointer to NULLs
memset( buffer, 0x00, (file_size* sizeof(char**) ) );

int buffer_counter = 0;
int buffer_length = 0;

while(0 < (buffer_length = getline( buffer[buffer_counter], file_size, datafile)))
{

    if ( 0 >= buffer_length )
    {
        status = EXITCODE_4;
        free2D(buffer, buffer_counter);
        return status;
    }

    // implied else, getline successful

    if((buffer[buffer_counter][buffer_length-1]) == NEWLINE)
    {
        // trim newline 
        buffer[buffer_counter][buffer_length-1] = '\0';
        buffer_length--;
    }

    buffer_counter++;
} // end while
```